# Matplotlib: How to show only one figure without closing the others?

Tags: python, matplotlib, show

Is it possible to do something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig_1, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,2,3])
fig_2, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([4,3,2,2])

fig_2.show()
```

in Python's matplotlib? I want to **display only `fig_2` without having to close `fig_1`?**

Comment: Your code works fine. It only displays `fig_2`. What do you mean by saying *close fig_1*?

Comment: My code does not display ```fig_2```. I have to call ```plt.show()``` if I want to see the plots, but it shows all the plots.

Comment: Your code works fine for matplotlib 3.2.1 and Python 3.6.8. What's your version?

Comment: I am using Python 3.8.2 with matplotlib 3.2.1 in Ubuntu 20.04.